# Need Good Resources to learn Drupal 7 module development

Tags: drupal

I am new to drupal 7 module development, i know php, html, css, javascript, suggest any resources like w3schools, for drupal 7 module development, i am expecting learn module development step by step with example

Comment: I've got the packt publishing book Drupal 7 module development, also worth installing the examples module and then reading through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is the best I've seen so far http://buildamodule.com. Packt book is good too